# Reachability startNotifier - does it require phone resources

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, reachability

I have to check internet connection sometimes and use "Reachability" for this purpose.

Would be better to manually checking internet connection using "Reachability" like:

```
BOOL status = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable);
```

Or use Reachability notifications and

```
//Start listening for reachability notifications on the current run loop
- (BOOL) startNotifier;
```

Do notifications require some phone recources like battery etc, and will I get some problems if I don't use "stopNotifier"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple:

- Use the singleton if you need to check whether you have an internet connection or not at a *certain point in time*
- Use the notifier + notifications if you need to keep track of changes in internet connectivity over a certain period of time

Comment: I thought it'd be clear from my answer, but you should use the singleton and not the notifiers in this case.

Answer (score 1):

IMO - using notifications is the way to go.  The Reachability class does a good job of keeping track of connectivity with minimal resources.  If you absolutely have to have connectivity to do something, then use the notifications.  Another benefit is that you can use the notifications to do something else (save the data locally, notify the user, etc).  You would want to use stopNotifier when you no longer care about connectivity.

Comment: I've found that a `Reachability` instance's `currentReachabilityStatus` is not accurate unless you've called `-startNotifier`, so I call `-startNotifier` even though I don't respond to the notifications. It's nice to know that it's not resource intensive.